# Change URL to RSS <link>, when <title> is clicked

Tags: jquery, redirect, rss

Good day all,

As the question states, I would like to have the page redirect to the url in the `<link>` once the `<title>` element of the RSS `<item>` is clicked.

The code in my JQUERY file looks like so,

JQUERY:

```
var rssUrl = $("item>link").html();

$("item>title").click(function(){
    $(location).attr("href",rssUrl);
});
```

HTML:

```
<p>
    <rss version="2.0">
        <channel>
        <item>
          <title>First Article</title>
          <link>http://www.google.com</link>
        </item>
        <br>
        <item>
          <title>Second Article</title>
          <link>http://www.stackoverflow.com</link>
        </item>
        </channel>
    </rss>
</p>
```

What's happening with this code, is that when I click the title it doesnt redirect to the desired page. The page just reloads.

I would like it so that clicking the FIRST ARTICLE, will redirect to Google. Clicking the SECOND ARTICLE, will redirect to StackOverflow.

I intend to add more `<item>`s, so I would like each `<title>` to have the page redirect to the corresponding `<link>`.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Hi guys, I still have not solved this issue. If anyone can assist, it will still be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$("item>title").click(function(){
    var url = $(this).next().text();
    window.location.replace(url); // or window.location.href = url
});
```

Comment: `@Felix` thanks for responding.

Your code isn't giving me any different results from before.

Could you say why it WOULD work, and why it possibly isnt working?

Comment: `@Felix`, there are errors. But nothing relating to the JQUERY.

Comment: Try to do an `alert` when your `title` clicked to check whether it work or not?

Comment: Good idea, `@Felix`. I placed an alert, which worked. Meaning, the alert popped up. I had commented out the code to change the url.

Comment: `@felix`, I decided to put the variable "url" in the alert. The window pops up blank.